# elasticsearch - "error" : "IndexMissingException[[_cluster] missing]",

Tags: elasticsearch

This page:

https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/elasticsearch-unassigned-shards/

suggests running:

`curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty`

but I get:

```
{
  "error" : "IndexMissingException[[_cluster] missing]",
  "status" : 404
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of elasticsearch are you running ?

Are you executing the below command on elasticsearch node or Kibana node ? Should be run on the node where elasticsearch is running

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty
```

A simpler way is to run the below command from Dev Tools on Kibana console

```
GET /_cluster/allocation/explain
```